# meaning of maintain a realistic perspective

Tags: vocabulary

It was difficult for the mayor **to maintain a realistic perspective** of the traffic problem after she was in a car accident.

Perspective: the ability to view things in their true relation or relative importance.

Not only could I get what is the exact concept of this sentence, I am wondering the reason why it was difficult, as well.

In addition, would you show me what the bold part means,here, exactly?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The word **realistic** is not the best choice of word. Objective would have been better.

To maintain a realistic perspective or to maintain an objective perspective means not to let personal bias interfere with one's judgment.

For example, the mayor had an accident at the intersection. Now she thinks it is a dangerous intersection. But perhaps there have been only two accidents there in the past five years, neither very serious, but at another intersection there have been twenty in the same time period.